# Printing with dot matrix printers via C# programming

Tags: c#, dot-matrix

I am using the code template from Microsoft at [this site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091) with this snippet to print out only a single line and form feed:

```
string s = "Hello world!\xC"; //\xC means form feed
PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
pd.PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings();
if (DialogResult.OK == pd.ShowDialog(this))
{
    RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName, s);
}
```

But no luck, my paper size long is always like A4 paper size long.

What is wrong with my code? Do anyone got a hint or trick to deal with this problem?

Comment: Are you having issues with the code, or with the printing?

Comment: Please explain what "my paper size long is always like A4 paper size long" means, and why that would be a problem.

Comment: Wow, dot matrix printers still exist? I thought those died with the 90's...

Comment: @Nathan: surprisingly enough, nobody's figured out yet how to make a laser or inkjet print through 4 carbons.  Those impact printers will be around for a very long time because they're cheap and reliable and do things that the lasers and inkjets can't.

Comment: @jnpcl, I'm having issues with printing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to say what the problem might be.  `SendStringToPrinter` ultimately ends up calling `WritePrinter`, which is supposed to copy what you send it to the printer unchanged.  A form feed is supposed to advance the paper vertically to the beginning of the next page.  "Next page" in this case is defined by the printer, and the printer's configuration will say how long a page is.

Are you perhaps wanting to advance just one line by using a line feed?

Comment: For the OP, a line feed is `\x0A` instead of `\x0C`.

Comment: you are right, paper can be advanced using line feed. and solved my problem, thanks for line feed "hack" :)


@Greg Hewgill and also thanks for line feed command.

Comment: @rasputin, if that solved the problem, then please select this as the accepted answer.